# How to do trivial algorithm for GUI calculator on C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, windows-phone-7, user-interface, calculator

For example I doing calculator for WP7.

[image]

This is my simple logic class:

```
public class CalcLogic
    {
        public static double Calculate(double a, double b, string operation)
        {
            double res = 0;
            switch (operation)
            {
                case ("+"):
                    res = a + b;
                    break;
                case ("-"):
                    res = a - b;
                    break;
                case ("*"):
                    res = a * b;
                    break;
                case ("/"):
                    res = a / b;
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

And this is in my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private const int Rows = 4, Cols = 4;
        private string[,] buttonTags = { { "7", "8", "9", "/" }, 
                                         { "4", "5", "6", "*" },
                                         { "1", "2", "3", "-" },
                                         { "0", "C", "=", "+" }
                                       };

        private Button[,] buttons;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateButtons();
        }

        public void CreateButtons()
        {
            buttons = new Button[Rows, Cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Cols; j++)
                {
                    buttons[i, j] = new Button();
                    buttons[i, j].Content = buttonTags[j, i];
                    buttons[i, j].Width = 120;
                    buttons[i, j].Height = 110;
                    buttons[i, j].Margin = new Thickness(i * 110 + 5, j * 110 + 100, 0, 0);
                    buttons[i, j].VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
                    buttons[i, j].HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    buttons[i, j].Name = "button" + buttonTags[j, i];
                    buttons[i, j].Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click);
                    ContentPanel.Children.Add(buttons[i, j]);
                    ContentPanel.UpdateLayout();
                }
            }
        }
```

And question is - how correct to do Button_Click method?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            tbResult.Text += button.Content.ToString();

            string operation = "";
            double a = 0;
            double b = 0;

            if (button.Content.ToString() == "=")
            {
                tbResult.Text = CalcLogic.Calculate(a, b, operation).ToString();
            }
            if (button.Content.ToString() == "C")
            {
                tbResult.Text = "";
            }

            ...

        }
```

Maybe I should just write to my TextBox digits and sign and after that parse? But I think it is not correct algorithm.

**UPD:**

That's what I did, it's working good. But I not sure about correct realization:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Button button = sender as Button;
                double res;
                if (Double.TryParse(button.Content.ToString(), out res))
                {
                    DigitClick(button.Content.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    OperatorClick(button.Content.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                ClearAll();
            }
        }


        private void ClearAll()
        {
            first = second = result = 0;
            operStr = "";
            newNum = true;
            tbResult.Text = "";
        }

        private void DigitClick(string dig)
        {
            if (newNum)
            {
                tbResult.Text = "";
            }
            tbResult.Text += dig;
            newNum = false;
        }

        private void OperatorClick(string oper)
        {
            if (oper == "=")
            {
                if (operStr == "=" || operStr == "")
                {
                    return;
                }
                second = Convert.ToInt32(tbResult.Text);
                result = CalcLogic.Calculate(first, second, operStr);
                tbResult.Text = result.ToString();
                operStr = oper;
            }
            else if (oper == "C")
            {
                ClearAll();
            }
            else
            {
                operStr = oper;
                first = Convert.ToInt32(tbResult.Text);
            }

            newNum = true;
        }
```

I just want to know best realization for GUI calculator, thanks.

Comment: What would 'best' mean to you? Less code? More efficient? Maintainable? Testable?

Comment: Yes, less code, efficient, maintainable and testable. This is simple program, and should be trivial golden mean.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, i would just simplify your logic. Like I said, OnClick should only do this: 
Append to your tbResult.Text the character that you pressed, then evaluate if character is "=". If that's the case then check if your tbResult.Text contains an operator character, then just use the string.Split function based on the operator character to parse first and second values and invoke your calculation and update the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but you are never assigning anything to your operation variable.  It's always an empty string.

Comment: Yes, but when I'll push to some sign, my variable "operation" must be change. But I don't know how correct to do it. I want to know how is correct to do GUI calc.